# How to get total in recursive function

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

How do I get the total interest paid on all months in the below recursive function?  This should simulate a credit card payment.

```
def creditcard_interest(balance,months,monthly_interest_rate=2.95/100):
    if months==1: 
        return print("The new balance= ",balance)
    else:
        min_monthly_payment=balance*0.05
        balance=balance-min_monthly_payment
        interest=balance*monthly_interest_rate
        print("Min_monthly_payment for month "+str(months)+'= ', min_monthly_payment)
        print("Unpaid balance  for month "+str(months)+'= ',balance)
        print("Calculated interest for month "+str(months)+'= ',interest)

        return  creditcard_interest((balance+interest),months-1,)
```

Comment: Don't `return print(...)` - return the balance instead i.e. `return balance`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Accumulate the interest as you return from each call:

```
return interest + creditcard_interest((balance+interest), months-1, )
```

BTW, your first statement is illegal: you can't return a print statement.  What are you trying to do with that?  Look at the semantics of your two branches: the first returns something relating to the balance, while the other apparently returns an interest amount.

I suspect that what you need to do is to `print` the balance, then `return` the interest.  Something like ...

```
interest=balance*monthly_interest_rate
if months==1:
    print("The new balance= ", balance)
    return interest
```

After changes,

```
print ("Total interest paid", creditcard_interest(1000, 12))
```

yields

```
Min_monthly_payment for month 12=  50.0
Unpaid balance  for month 12=  950.0
Calculated interest for month 12=  29.500000000000004
Min_monthly_payment for month 11=  48.975
Unpaid balance  for month 11=  930.525
Calculated interest for month 11=  28.89525
Min_monthly_payment for month 10=  47.9710125
Unpaid balance  for month 10=  911.4492375
Calculated interest for month 10=  28.302897375
Min_monthly_payment for month 9=  46.98760674375001
Unpaid balance  for month 9=  892.76452813125
Calculated interest for month 9=  27.722687978812502
Min_monthly_payment for month 8=  46.02436080550313
Unpaid balance  for month 8=  874.4628553045594
Calculated interest for month 8=  27.154372875246846
Min_monthly_payment for month 7=  45.080861408990316
Unpaid balance  for month 7=  856.5363667708159
Calculated interest for month 7=  26.597708231304285
Min_monthly_payment for month 6=  44.15670375010601
Unpaid balance  for month 6=  838.9773712520142
Calculated interest for month 6=  26.05245521256255
Min_monthly_payment for month 5=  43.25149132322884
Unpaid balance  for month 5=  821.778335141348
Calculated interest for month 5=  25.518379880705016
Min_monthly_payment for month 4=  42.364835751102646
Unpaid balance  for month 4=  804.9318792709503
Calculated interest for month 4=  24.995253093150563
Min_monthly_payment for month 3=  41.49635661820505
Unpaid balance  for month 3=  788.4307757458959
Calculated interest for month 3=  24.48285040474098
Min_monthly_payment for month 2=  40.645681307531845
Unpaid balance  for month 2=  772.2679448431049
Calculated interest for month 2=  23.980951971443787
The new balance=  796.2488968145487
Total interest paid 23.48934245602919
```

You still have a base case (end condition) to handle, and perhaps some formatting issues, but this fixed the main problems.